# How to prevent browser tab/window close when I'm in onbeforeunload event?

Tags: javascript

I want to show a custom ***Are you sure you want to leave this page?*** dialog box (in ExtJs) in the `window.onbeforeunload` event. I am familiar with the fact that if I return a string from this method, it would show a "browser" pop up with the returned message on it; however, I don't want the regular pop up at all.

Now, the issue is that as soon as `window.onbeforeunload` function finishes executing, ExtJs dialog box or anything on the screen doesn't matter anymore and the browser tab closes. I tried `stopImmediatePropagation`, `stopPropagation` methods and setting `cancelBubble` property to `true`. However, nothing seems to work. I'm sorry, I don't even know if they are supposed to work.

Here is the code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){

    Ext.Msg.show({
        title:'Warning',
        msg: 'Are you sure?',
        buttons: Ext.Msg.YESNO,
        icon: Ext.Msg.QUESTION,
        fn: function (btn) {
            if (btn == 'yes') {
                //Close Browser Window
            }
        },
        modal: true
    });

    //A desperate attempt to stop window/tab from closing
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    //This brings up default browser pop up
    //return 'Message';
};
```

I'm sorry, I won't be able to create a Sencha Fiddle because it has it's own *Confirm Navigation* dialog box.

I want to know if it's possible to implement this? If yes, then how?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own) about this no choice to make a custom (extjs etc) dialog